# Running SQLAlchemy-Migrate migration raises ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

When I try and run a SQLAlchemy-Migrate migration it gives me the following error:

```
  File "c:\users\achim\DOCUME~1\VISUAL~1\Projects\FFAWUZ\FFAWUZ\env\lib\site-
packages\migrate\versioning\genmodel.py", line 219, in genB2AMigration
    for modelCol, databaseCol, modelDecl, databaseDecl in td.columns_different:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I have seen this before. The last time it was due to the columns I had updated which contained data items. However, this time adding new columns gave the error.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250901/python-sql-alchemy-migrate-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-when-migrat.